# How to iterate through n arrayed DOM elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a form using Javascript. The validation function aims to iterate through a variable number of input elements which have been named using an array format so that they come through properly in $_POST. However, I'm having trouble iterating through these elements with Javascript - does anybody know how to access these from simple Javascript?

Here's my validation function and a cut down version of my form to help illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var vTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById('Total'));
    var subtotal = 0;

    var sub = document.getElementsByName('subqty');
    for ( var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++ ) {
        if ( sub[i].value != "" ) {
            subtotal += parseInt(sub[i].value);
            }
        }

    if ( subtotal != vTotal ) {
        alert("Totals do not match, please check your math and try again.");
        return false;
        }
    }
</script>

....

<form name="test" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<input type="text" id="Total" value="100"><br>

<!-- there can be any number of subtotal inputs -->
<input type="text" name="subqty[1]" value="30"><br>
<input type="text" name="subqty[2]" value="10"><br>
<input type="text" name="subqty[3]" value="43"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Check Validation">
</form>
```

So far I am receiving an error that the parser cannot read the property "length" of type NULL - so it would appear that using getElementsByName on an array of input elements is not valid? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: None of your elements have the name `subqty`, so nothing matches. Just give the elements a common class, and use that instead. Javascript and HTML doesn't really care about "array named" elements, only PHP *(and some other serverside languages)* do.

Comment: Also, grouping inputs is generally for radio buttons and the like, for your text inputs you really should just use regular names.

Comment: @adeneo Grouping would be done by giving them the *same* name, which isn't the case here anyway. Indexing them is a common approach for arbitrarily many inputs, e.g. in lists.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, that did work - switched to getElementsByClassName() and assigned the elements a common class. Bergi is right, naming inputs as arrays in this case is necessary because it is a dynamic form which can shrink or grow based on user action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**CSS Attribute-Begin-With Selector**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) like this:

```
var sub = document.querySelectorAll("[name^='subqty']");
```

More CSS selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input type="text" id="Total" value="100"><br>
        <div id="subForm">
            <!-- there can be any number of subtotal inputs -->
            <input type="text" name="subqty[1]" value="30"><br>
            <input type="text" name="subqty[2]" value="10"><br>
            <input type="text" name="subqty[3]" value="43"><br>
       </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Check Validation">
</form>
```

JavaSript

```
function validateForm() {
    var vTotal = document.getElementById('Total').value;
    var subtotal = 0;

    var sub = document.querySelectorAll('#subForm input');
    for ( var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++ ) {
        if ( sub[i].value != "" ) {
            subtotal += parseInt(sub[i].value);
        } else {
            alert('Please fill all fields!');
        }
    }

    if ( subtotal != vTotal ) {
        alert("Totals do not match, please check your math and try again.");
        return false;
        } else {
            alert('Everything is wright!');
            return true;
        }
    }
```